# "/usr/bin/env node: No such file of directory" - only under Supervisor

Tags: node.js, supervisord

When I try to run Node.js applications from under Supervisor I get following error:

```
/usr/bin/env node: No such file of directory
```

It is a machine running Ubuntu 16.04 and actually there is /usr/bin/node installed and it is symlinked to /usr/bin/nodejs. I installed it from [Node.js repository](https://nodejs.org/en/download/package-manager/#debian-and-ubuntu-based-linux-distributions). So when I run

```
node -v
/usr/bin/env node -v
```

I get:

```
v9.7.1
```

My application's configuration for Supervisor (v 3.2.0) is:

```
[program:verdaccio]
command=/usr/bin/verdaccio
autostart=true
autorestart=true
user=ubu
environment=HOME="/home/ubu",USER="ubu",PATH="$PATH:/home/ubu/.local/bin"
```

What's wrong?

Comment: Excuse me, what's wrong with this question that it gets downvotes? I had real problem, described it quite thoroughly, spend an hour to find an answer and seeing no duplicate wanted to share an answer. So why downvote it?

Answer (score 5):

if you are using `nvm` node version manager, use this comment to create a symlink:

```
sudo ln -s "$(which node)" /usr/bin/node
```

Comment: this works for me, thanks for saving my day

Comment: Thanks a lot. Work for me; use it if you are using nvm.

Answer (score 2):

Turns out it is quite simple but has nothing to do with "no symlink to /usr/bin/node" problem of people that installed Node.js from standard system's repo.

It is a Supervisor's task configuration problem. Namely that

```
PATH="$PATH:/home/ubu/.local/bin"
```

is messing things up. It is an artifact from a time when I ran Node from ~/.local/bin not globally. Just deleted it, reloaded the supervisor and now the application is running nicely :)

Hope it helps someone.

Answer (score 0):

Most times this is a simple naming problem, when you install from a package manager your bin file may be called nodejs so you just need to symlink it using the command:

```
ln -s /usr/bin/nodejs /usr/bin/node
```